# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, sockets, permissions, daemon

I'm trying to run a simple build on teamcity with docker on windows and use powershell for my commands. On teamcity I'm logged in as a super user and this build uses the command line to show the docker version. When I run this build I get this error message:

```
[15:30:55]Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
[15:30:55]Process exited with code 1
```

I'm using the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  teamcity:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    volumes:
      - teamcity-server-datadir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - teamcity-server-logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
    ports:
      - 8111:8111
  teamcity-agent:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent
    environment:
      SERVER_URL: http://teamcity:8111
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
volumes:
  teamcity-server-datadir:
  teamcity-server-logs:
```

I have tried the workaround to add a group user with the sudo commands, but sudo is not recognized.
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you try `usermod -a -G docker $USER` ?  Any user belonging to the docker group can connect to the socket.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the command you proposed, but then I get the following error:

"usermod: The term 'usermod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Sorry for the late reply. I was on holiday. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This error was caused by TeamCity agent Docker images now run under a non-root user. I can not find a solution so I started to use earlier versions(2019.1). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/upgrade-notes.html#Agent+Docker+images+run+under+non-root+user